# Step Functions error handler function parameters

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-step-functions

I'm working in this project where we create a AWS Lambda serverless architecture and those async functions are running as Step Functions. I was told to code the error handler part. Basically we got a cloudformation template and there you can clearly see error handler basically is responsible to log those errors. So here comes my problem, other developers who already developed other parts just throw Error if anything goes wrong in their async lambda functions and in cloudformation template we got the definition as

```
{
  "Variable": "$.status",
  "StringEquals": "FAILED",
  "Next": "Handle Error"
}
```

for those functions. Now in my ErrorHandler Lambda function I have to get those errors and check their type and codes etc. What I don't understand is how those errors are being passed to my ErrorHandler? Also how can I know which function has thrown that error to understand which step failed? I've searched github, aws doc but they don't talk about the code at all.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From your question it seems you have a "one error handler to rule them all" type of error handling. I don't think you can achieve what you need with this structure.

> Also how can I know which function has thrown that error to understand which step failed?

Exactly. Not so straightforward with a single error handler.

What you can do instead is to configure `Catch` for each of the tasks which can fail (i.e. where you care about failures). Thus you'll know which task failed implicitly.

> So here comes my problem, other developers who already developed other parts just throw Error if anything goes wrong in their async lambda functions

That's another problem. If tasks just throw `Error` indiscriminately, you'll have to build workarounds to compensate for this.

A better option is to implement specific errors for specific failures and throw them instead of `Error`. Something like:

```
function MySpecificError(message) {
    this.name = 'MySpecificError';
    this.message = message;
}
MySpecificError.prototype = new Error();
```

Then, one can return this error:

```
callback(new MySpecificError("Something specific happened."));
```

Now, in your state machine you'll be able to distinguish failure causes and act accordingly:

```
               "Catch":[
                  {
                    "ErrorEquals":[
                       "MySpecificError"
                    ],
                    "Next": "HandleSpecificError"
                  }
               ]
```

Comment: catch statement and everything is in place for each function and they all define error handler function as the Next target for catch. What I want to know is, how can I reach this error object, message... in error handler function now? It has been thrown from the function X along the way now step functions ended up in error handler function I've coded. This error is somehow provided to error handler function as an argument? Or maybe it is stored in context object (I couldnt find any info about this). All I want is to get this thrown error in my error handler function somehow.